# SQL Error SQLSTATE[HY093]: Invalid parameter number

Tags: php, pdo

This code grabs data from my server and allows me to edit and save the data back into the server. Error is clearly coming from the SQL but I can't see to figure out why.

I've been going over this code for hours trying to find where it's giving me error SQLSTATE[HY093]: Invalid parameter number, but I can't seem to find it.

As far as I can tell all the parameters match.

Do you guys see anything I'm missing?

```
<?php require 'templates/header.php'; ?>
<?php include '../common.php'; ?>

    <!-- container -->
    <div class="container">
  
        <div class="page-header">
            <h1>Update Product</h1>
        </div>
     
        <?php 

            $id=isset($_GET['id']) ? $_GET['id'] : die('Error: Record ID not found.'); 

            include '../config.php';

            try {
                
                $connection = new PDO($dsn, $username, $password, $options); 

                //Prepare select query
                $sql = 'SELECT * FROM inspections WHERE id = ? LIMIT 0,1';
                $statement = $connection->prepare($sql);
                
                $statement->bindParam(1, $id); 
                
                //execute query
                $statement->execute();

                //store retrieved row to a variable
                $row = $statement->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

                //values to fill up the form
                $inspectionAddress         = $row['inspectionAddress'];
                $city                      = $row['city'];
                $zipCode                   = $row['zipCode'];
                $subdivision               = $row['subdivision'];
                $unitNumber                = $row['unitNumber'];
                $buildingNumber            = $row['buildingNumber'];
                $squareFootage             = $row['squareFootage'];
                $stories                   = $row['stories'];
                $year                      = $row['year'];
                $bedroomNumber             = $row['bedroomNumber'];
                $bathroomNumber            = $row['bathroomNumber'];
                $garageNumber              = $row['garageNumber'];
                $acNumber                  = $row['acNumber'];
                $buyerFirstName            = $row['buyerFirstName'];
                $buyerLastName             = $row['buyerLastName'];
                $buyerCellPhone            = $row['buyerCellPhone'];
                $buyerEmail                = $row['buyerEmail'];
                $buyerHomePhone            = $row['buyer2Phone'];
                $buyerAgentOfficeName      = $row['buyerAgentOfficeName'];
                $buyerAgentName            = $row['buyerAgentName'];
                $buyerAgentCellPhone       = $row['buyerAgent1Phone'];
                $buyerAgentEmail           = $row['buyerAgent1Email'];
                $buyerAgentOfficePhone     = $row['buyerAgent2Phone'];
                $sellerLastName            = $row['sellerLastName'];
                $sellerCellPhone           = $row['sellerPhone1'];
                $sellAgentOfficeName       = $row['sellAgentOfficeName'];
                $sellAgentName             = $row['sellAgentName'];
                $sellAgentCellPhone        = $row['sellAgentCellPhone'];
                $sellAgentOfficePhone      = $row['sellAgentOfficePhone'];
                $inspectionNumber          = $row['inspectionNumber'];
                $inspectionDate            = $row['inspectionDate'];
                $inspectionDay             = $row['inspectionDay'];
                $inspectionTime            = $row['inspectionTime'];
                $inspector                 = $row['mainInspector'];
                $roofer                    = $row['roofInspector'];
                $termite                   = $row['termiteInspector'];
                $fullInspection            = $row['fullInspection'];
                $fullpoolInspection        = $row['fullPoolInspection'];
                $townhousevillaInspection  = $row['townhouseVillaInspection'];
                $condoInspection           = $row['condoInspection'];
                $duplexInspection          = $row['duplexInspection'];
                $triplexInspection         = $row['triplexInspection'];
                $fourplexInspection        = $row['fourplexInspection'];
                $mitigationInspection      = $row['mitigationInspection'];
                $fourptInspection          = $row['fourPointInspection'];
                $addlAreasWell             = $row['addlAreasWell'];
                $addlAreasSeaWall          = $row['addlAreasSeaWall'];
                $addlAreasMold             = $row['addlAreasMold'];
                $addlAreasCrawlSpace       = $row['addlAreasCrawlSpace'];
                $addlAreasExtraStructure   = $row['addlAreasExtraStructure'];
                $addlAreasOther            = $row['addlAreasOther'];
                $additionalNotes           = $row['additionalNotes'];
                $scheduledBy               = $row['scheduledBy'];
                $referredBy                = $row['referredBy'];
                $cbsCode                   = $row['cbsCode'];
                $lockboxCode               = $row['lockboxCode'];
                $gateCode                  = $row['gateCode'];
                $county                    = $row['county'];
            } catch (PDOException $error) {
                echo $sql . "<br>" . $error->getMessage();
            }

        ?>
 
        <?php
        
        // check if form was submitted
        if($_POST){
            
            try{
            
                // write update query
                $sql = "UPDATE inspections 
                            SET id = :id,
                            inspectionAddress = :inspectionAddress,
                            city = :city,
                            zipCode = :zipCode,
                            subdivision = :subdivision,
                            unitNumber = :unitNumber,
                            buildingNumber = :buildingNumber,
                            squareFootage = :squareFootage,
                            stories = :stories,
                            year = :year,
                            bedroomNumber = :bedroomNumber,
                            bathroomNumber = :bathroomNumber,
                            garageNumber = :garageNumber,
                            acNumber = :acNumber,
                            buyerFirstName = :buyerFirstName,
                            buyerLastName = :buyerLastName,
                            buyerCellPhone = :buyerCellPhone,
                            buyerEmail = :buyerEmail,
                            buyer2Phone = :buyer2Phone,
                            buyerAgentOfficeName = :buyerAgentOfficeName,
                            buyerAgentName = :buyerAgentName,
                            buyerAgent1Phone = :buyerAgent1Phone,
                            buyerAgent1Email = :buyerAgent1Email,
                            buyerAgent2Phone = :buyerAgent2Phone,
                            sellerLastName = :sellerLastName,
                            sellerPhone1 = :sellerPhone1,
                            sellAgentOfficeName = :sellAgentOfficeName,
                            sellAgentName = :sellAgentName,
                            sellAgentCellPhone = :sellAgentCellPhone,
                            sellAgentOfficePhone = :sellAgentOfficePhone,
                            inspectionNumber = :inspectionNumber,
                            inspectionDate = :inspectionDate,
                            inspectionDay = :inspectionDay,
                            inspectionTime = :inspectionTime,
                            mainInspector = :mainInspector,
                            roofInspector = :roofInspector,
                            termiteInspector = :termiteInspector,
                            fullInspection = :fullInspection,
                            fullPoolInspection = :fullPoolInspection,
                            townhouseVillaInspection = :townhouseVillaInspection,
                            condoInspection = :condoInspection,
                            duplexInspection = :duplexInspection,
                            triplexInspection = :triplexInspection,
                            fourplexInspection = :fourplexInspection,
                            mitigationInspection = :mitigationInspection,
                            fourPointInspection = :fourPointInspection,
                            addlAreasWell = :addlAreasWell,
                            addlAreasSeaWall = :addlAreasSeaWall,
                            addlAreasMold = :addlAreasMold,
                            addlAreasCrawlSpace = :addlAreasCrawlSpace,
                            addlAreasExtraStructure = :addlAreasExtraStructure,
                            addlAreasOther = :addlAreasOther,
                            additionalNotes = :additionalNotes,
                            scheduledBy = :scheduledBy,
                            referredBy = :referredBy,
                            cbsCode = :cbsCode,
                            lockboxCode = :lockboxCode,
                            gateCode = :gateCode,
                            county = :county
                            WHERE id = :id";
                
                
                // prepare query for excecution
                $statement = $connection->prepare($sql);
        
                // posted values
                $inspectionAddress         = escapePost('streetAddress');
                $city                      = escapePost('city');
                $zipCode                   = escapePost('zipCode');
                $subdivision               = escapePost('subdivision');
                $unitNumber                = escapePost('unitNumber');
                $buildingNumber            = escapePost('buildingNumber');
                $squareFootage             = escapePost('squareFootage');
                $stories                   = escapePost('stories');
                $year                      = escapePost('year');
                $bedroomNumber             = escapePost('bedroomNumber');
                $bathroomNumber            = escapePost('bathroomNumber');
                $garageNumber              = escapePost('garageNumber');
                $acNumber                  = escapePost('acNumber');
                $buyerFirstName            = escapePost('buyerFirstName');
                $buyerLastName             = escapePost('buyerLastName');
                $buyerCellPhone            = escapePost('buyerCellPhone');
                $buyerEmail                = escapePost('buyerEmail');
                $buyerHomePhone            = escapePost('buyerCellPhone');
                $buyerAgentOfficeName      = escapePost('buyerAgentOfficeName');
                $buyerAgentName            = escapePost('buyerAgentName');
                $buyerAgentCellPhone       = escapePost('buyerAgentCellPhone');
                $buyerAgentEmail           = escapePost('buyerAgentEmail');
                $buyerAgentOfficePhone     = escapePost('buyerAgentOfficePhone');
                $sellerLastName            = escapePost('sellerLastName');
                $sellerCellPhone           = escapePost('sellerCellPhone');
                $sellAgentOfficeName       = escapePost('sellAgentOfficeName');
                $sellAgentName             = escapePost('sellAgentName');
                $sellAgentCellPhone        = escapePost('sellAgentCellPhone');
                $sellAgentOfficePhone      = escapePost('sellAgentOfficePhone');
                $inspectionNumber          = escapePost('inspectionNumber');
                $inspectionDate            = escapePost('inspectionDate');
                $inspectionDay             = escapePost('inspectionDay');
                $inspectionTime            = escapePost('inspectionTime');
                $inspector                 = escapePost('inspector');
                $roofer                    = escapePost('roofer');
                $termite                   = escapePost('termite');
                $fullInspection            = escapePost('fullInspection');
                $fullpoolInspection        = escapePost('full-poolInspection');
                $townhousevillaInspection  = escapePost('townhouse-villaInspection');
                $condoInspection           = escapePost('condoInspection');
                $duplexInspection          = escapePost('duplexInspection');
                $triplexInspection         = escapePost('triplexInspection');
                $fourplexInspection        = escapePost('fourplexInspection');
                $mitigationInspection      = escapePost('mitigationInspection');
                $fourptInspection          = escapePost('4ptInspection');
                $addlAreasWell             = escapePost('addlAreasWell');
                $addlAreasSeaWall          = escapePost('addlAreasSeaWall');
                $addlAreasMold             = escapePost('addlAreasMold');
                $addlAreasCrawlSpace       = escapePost('addlAreasCrawlSpace');
                $addlAreasExtraStructure   = escapePost('addlAreasExtraStructure');
                $addlAreasOther            = escapePost('addlAreasOther');
                $additionalNotes           = escapePost('additionalNotes');
                $scheduledBy               = escapePost('scheduledBy');
                $referredBy                = escapePost('referredBy');
                $cbsCode                   = escapePost('cbsCode');
                $lockboxCode               = escapePost('lockboxCode');
                $gateCode                  = escapePost('gateCode');
                $county                    = escapePost('county');
        
                // bind the parameters
                $statement->bindParam(':inspectionAddress', $inspectionAddress);
                $statement->bindParam(':city', $city);
                $statement->bindParam(':zipCode', $zipCode);
                $statement->bindParam(':subdivision', $subdivision);
                $statement->bindParam(':unitNumber', $unitNumber);
                $statement->bindParam(':buildingNumber', $buildingNumber);
                $statement->bindParam(':squareFootage', $squareFootage);
                $statement->bindParam(':stories', $stories);
                $statement->bindParam(':year', $year);
                $statement->bindParam(':bedroomNumber', $bedroomNumber);
                $statement->bindParam(':bathroomNumber', $bathroomNumber);
                $statement->bindParam(':garageNumber', $garageNumber);
                $statement->bindParam(':acNumber', $acNumber);
                $statement->bindParam(':buyerFirstName', $buyerFirstName);
                $statement->bindParam(':buyerLastName', $buyerLastName);
                $statement->bindParam(':buyerCellPhone', $buyerCellPhone);
                $statement->bindParam(':buyerEmail', $buyerEmail);
                $statement->bindParam(':buyer2Phone', $buyer2Phone);
                $statement->bindParam(':buyerAgentOfficeName', $buyerAgentOfficeName);
                $statement->bindParam(':buyerAgentName', $buyerAgentName);
                $statement->bindParam(':buyerAgent1Phone', $buyerAgent1Phone);
                $statement->bindParam(':buyerAgent1Email', $buyerAgent1Email);
                $statement->bindParam(':buyerAgent2Phone', $buyerAgent2Phone);
                $statement->bindParam(':sellerLastName', $sellerLastName);
                $statement->bindParam(':sellerPhone1', $sellerPhone1);
                $statement->bindParam(':sellAgentOfficeName', $sellAgentOfficeName);
                $statement->bindParam(':sellAgentName', $sellAgentName);
                $statement->bindParam(':sellAgentCellPhone', $sellAgentCellPhone);
                $statement->bindParam(':sellAgentOfficePhone', $sellAgentOfficePhone);
                $statement->bindParam(':inspectionNumber', $inspectionNumber);
                $statement->bindParam(':inspectionDate', $inspectionDate);
                $statement->bindParam(':inspectionDay', $inspectionDay);
                $statement->bindParam(':inspectionTime', $inspectionTime);
                $statement->bindParam(':mainInspector', $mainInspector);
                $statement->bindParam(':roofInspector', $roofInspector);
                $statement->bindParam(':termiteInspector', $termiteInspector);
                $statement->bindParam(':fullInspection', $fullInspection);
                $statement->bindParam(':fullPoolInspection', $fullPoolInspection);
                $statement->bindParam(':townhouseVillaInspection', $townhouseVillaInspection);
                $statement->bindParam(':condoInspection', $condoInspection);
                $statement->bindParam(':duplexInspection', $duplexInspection);
                $statement->bindParam(':triplexInspection', $triplexInspection);
                $statement->bindParam(':fourplexInspection', $fourplexInspection);
                $statement->bindParam(':mitigationInspection', $mitigationInspection);
                $statement->bindParam(':fourPointInspection', $fourPointInspection);
                $statement->bindParam(':addlAreasWell', $addlAreasWell);
                $statement->bindParam(':addlAreasSeaWall', $addlAreasSeaWall);
                $statement->bindParam(':addlAreasMold', $addlAreasMold);
                $statement->bindParam(':addlAreasCrawlSpace', $addlAreasCrawlSpace);
                $statement->bindParam(':addlAreasExtraStructure', $addlAreasExtraStructure);
                $statement->bindParam(':addlAreasOther', $addlAreasOther);
                $statement->bindParam(':additionalNotes', $additionalNotes);
                $statement->bindParam(':scheduledBy', $scheduledBy);
                $statement->bindParam(':referredBy', $referredBy);
                $statement->bindParam(':cbsCode', $cbsCode);
                $statement->bindParam(':lockboxCode', $lockboxCode);
                $statement->bindParam(':gateCode', $gateCode);
                $statement->bindParam(':county', $county);
                $statement->bindParam(':id', $id);

                // Execute the query
                if($statement->execute()){
                    echo "<div class='alert alert-success'>Record was updated.</div>";
                }else{
                    echo "<div class='alert alert-danger'>Unable to update record. Please try again.</div>";
                }
                
            }
            
            // show errors
            catch(PDOException $error){
                echo $sql . "<br>" . $error->getMessage();
            }
        }
        ?>
```

common.php:

```
<?php

/**
 * Ths file will store functions we may need to use. 
 */


 // Escape HTML for output: 

function escape($html) {
    return htmlspecialchars($html, ENT_QUOTES | ENT_SUBSTITUTE, "UTF-8"); 
};

function escapePost($posted) {
    return htmlspecialchars(strip_tags($_POST[$posted])); 
}

?>
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question and include the exact and complete contents of the error message you are receiving. While debugging it can also help to not use try/catch so the full error is shown.

Comment: If you are preparing and binding values LIKE YOU ARE, there is no benefit in escaping the values, so why are you doing that

Comment: 60 lines in the prepare and 59 in the bindParam section ?? Rocket science it aint. Also you use `:id` twice you may need to do  an `:id1` for one of them as 2 params with the same name can cause issues

Comment: Never use `htmlspecialchars` when inserting the data into the database. This function should only be used when outputting to HTML

Answer (score -3):

You update column that include in where condition.
Change:

```
$sql = "UPDATE inspections 
                            SET id = :id,
                            inspectionAddress = :inspectionAddress,
                            city = :city,
                            zipCode = :zipCode,
                            subdivision = :subdivision,
                            unitNumber = :unitNumber,
                            buildingNumber = :buildingNumber,
                            squareFootage = :squareFootage,
                            stories = :stories,
                            year = :year,
                            bedroomNumber = :bedroomNumber,
                            bathroomNumber = :bathroomNumber,
                            garageNumber = :garageNumber,
                            acNumber = :acNumber,
                            buyerFirstName = :buyerFirstName,
                            buyerLastName = :buyerLastName,
                            buyerCellPhone = :buyerCellPhone,
                            buyerEmail = :buyerEmail,
                            buyer2Phone = :buyer2Phone,
                            buyerAgentOfficeName = :buyerAgentOfficeName,
                            buyerAgentName = :buyerAgentName,
                            buyerAgent1Phone = :buyerAgent1Phone,
                            buyerAgent1Email = :buyerAgent1Email,
                            buyerAgent2Phone = :buyerAgent2Phone,
                            sellerLastName = :sellerLastName,
                            sellerPhone1 = :sellerPhone1,
                            sellAgentOfficeName = :sellAgentOfficeName,
                            sellAgentName = :sellAgentName,
                            sellAgentCellPhone = :sellAgentCellPhone,
                            sellAgentOfficePhone = :sellAgentOfficePhone,
                            inspectionNumber = :inspectionNumber,
                            inspectionDate = :inspectionDate,
                            inspectionDay = :inspectionDay,
                            inspectionTime = :inspectionTime,
                            mainInspector = :mainInspector,
                            roofInspector = :roofInspector,
                            termiteInspector = :termiteInspector,
                            fullInspection = :fullInspection,
                            fullPoolInspection = :fullPoolInspection,
                            townhouseVillaInspection = :townhouseVillaInspection,
                            condoInspection = :condoInspection,
                            duplexInspection = :duplexInspection,
                            triplexInspection = :triplexInspection,
                            fourplexInspection = :fourplexInspection,
                            mitigationInspection = :mitigationInspection,
                            fourPointInspection = :fourPointInspection,
                            addlAreasWell = :addlAreasWell,
                            addlAreasSeaWall = :addlAreasSeaWall,
                            addlAreasMold = :addlAreasMold,
                            addlAreasCrawlSpace = :addlAreasCrawlSpace,
                            addlAreasExtraStructure = :addlAreasExtraStructure,
                            addlAreasOther = :addlAreasOther,
                            additionalNotes = :additionalNotes,
                            scheduledBy = :scheduledBy,
                            referredBy = :referredBy,
                            cbsCode = :cbsCode,
                            lockboxCode = :lockboxCode,
                            gateCode = :gateCode,
                            county = :county
                            WHERE id = :id";
```

Into:

```
$sql = "UPDATE inspections SET
                            inspectionAddress = :inspectionAddress,
                            city = :city,
                            zipCode = :zipCode,
                            subdivision = :subdivision,
                            unitNumber = :unitNumber,
                            buildingNumber = :buildingNumber,
                            squareFootage = :squareFootage,
                            stories = :stories,
                            year = :year,
                            bedroomNumber = :bedroomNumber,
                            bathroomNumber = :bathroomNumber,
                            garageNumber = :garageNumber,
                            acNumber = :acNumber,
                            buyerFirstName = :buyerFirstName,
                            buyerLastName = :buyerLastName,
                            buyerCellPhone = :buyerCellPhone,
                            buyerEmail = :buyerEmail,
                            buyer2Phone = :buyer2Phone,
                            buyerAgentOfficeName = :buyerAgentOfficeName,
                            buyerAgentName = :buyerAgentName,
                            buyerAgent1Phone = :buyerAgent1Phone,
                            buyerAgent1Email = :buyerAgent1Email,
                            buyerAgent2Phone = :buyerAgent2Phone,
                            sellerLastName = :sellerLastName,
                            sellerPhone1 = :sellerPhone1,
                            sellAgentOfficeName = :sellAgentOfficeName,
                            sellAgentName = :sellAgentName,
                            sellAgentCellPhone = :sellAgentCellPhone,
                            sellAgentOfficePhone = :sellAgentOfficePhone,
                            inspectionNumber = :inspectionNumber,
                            inspectionDate = :inspectionDate,
                            inspectionDay = :inspectionDay,
                            inspectionTime = :inspectionTime,
                            mainInspector = :mainInspector,
                            roofInspector = :roofInspector,
                            termiteInspector = :termiteInspector,
                            fullInspection = :fullInspection,
                            fullPoolInspection = :fullPoolInspection,
                            townhouseVillaInspection = :townhouseVillaInspection,
                            condoInspection = :condoInspection,
                            duplexInspection = :duplexInspection,
                            triplexInspection = :triplexInspection,
                            fourplexInspection = :fourplexInspection,
                            mitigationInspection = :mitigationInspection,
                            fourPointInspection = :fourPointInspection,
                            addlAreasWell = :addlAreasWell,
                            addlAreasSeaWall = :addlAreasSeaWall,
                            addlAreasMold = :addlAreasMold,
                            addlAreasCrawlSpace = :addlAreasCrawlSpace,
                            addlAreasExtraStructure = :addlAreasExtraStructure,
                            addlAreasOther = :addlAreasOther,
                            additionalNotes = :additionalNotes,
                            scheduledBy = :scheduledBy,
                            referredBy = :referredBy,
                            cbsCode = :cbsCode,
                            lockboxCode = :lockboxCode,
                            gateCode = :gateCode,
                            county = :county
                            WHERE id = :id";
```

Comment: Exactly how does this solve the problem? You may set the value used in the where clause if you need to.